# Castor Marshaller to return empty tags for null objects

Tags: object, tags, null, castor

We are using Castor to unmarshall the Castor object to XML string. Castor is not generating Empty tags for null objects. Is there a API available to set it as parameter while unmarshalling?

There is a way to handle it by using the handler and override convertUponGet method to return empty string. But, Is there a better to do it?

Any clues will help.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have seen there are 3 ways of dealing with this in order of best to worst.

1. Use a GeneralizedFieldHandler as explained in [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9176479/how-to-tell-castor-to-marshall-a-null-field-to-an-empty-tag](http://www.mail-archive.com/castor-dev@exolab.org/msg19024.html).  The field handler is reusable for other fields and doesn't change the behavior of your class.
2. Modify your get method for the given field to check for nulls and return an empty string if it is null.  This approach changes the behavior of your class so if you have other parts of your code relying on nulls for this field, which also isn't a good idea, you will run into problems.
3. Modify Castor yourself to return an empty string when a null is encountered.  Usually a really bad idea changing a tool you are using, unless you submit it back to the developers of the project to integrate into their code base for future releases.  This doesn't seem likely since this issue was brought up back in 2007 http://old.nabble.com/Forcing-marshalling-of-null-empty-values--to9080721.html#a9096375 if not earlier